# Irregular Fuel Pressure and a Old Clogged Fuel Filter

Tags: rough-idle

I was reading this article on [vapor lock](http://www.gearheaddiva.com/3422/troubleshooting-an-engine-that-stalls-at-idle-when-warm/) regarding my intermittent hot weather idle problems, and was wondering if an old, clogged fuel filter could cause intermittent fuel pressure problems and put stress on the fuel pump and make it overheat and stall when the fuel is low and it's hot outside.

Comment: It could cause the issue. Most fuel filters are cheap and easy to replace ... replace it and find out.

Comment: Rethinking my comment ... the fuel filter is usually in a place which doesn't suffer from getting heated up. Plus it has fuel running through it which will help to cool it. If you think you it's fuel pressure causing you issues, put a fuel pressure gauge on your vehicle and check it while running. If the fuel filter is old, go ahead and replace it as it will need it anyway.

Comment: @Paulster2 my fuel filter is on the firewall right behind the engine but yeah I'm going to go ahead and replace it and see if that helps since its in a spot where it gets heat from the engine and no air flow.

Comment: Remember there could be other things responsible for your intermittent issues. To eliminate speculation I would monitor fuel pressure with a gauge to see if it correlates with when you observe issues. There should be a schrader valve somewhere on the fuel lines that should allow you to do this.

Comment: @Zaid If the problem doesn't go away after changing the fuel filter ( which is way, way overdue anyways ) then I'll for sure check with a pressure gauge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fuel filter is usually in a place which doesn't suffer from getting heated up. Plus it has fuel running through it which will help to cool it. If you think it's fuel pressure causing you issues, put a fuel pressure gauge on your vehicle and check it while running. If the fuel filter is old, go ahead and replace it as it will need it anyway.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced the fuel filter, a real pita on this model.  Are fuel pressure gauges expensive?

Comment: I got [this one from Sears](http://www.sears.com/sunpro-fuel-pressure-tester/p-00902169000P?sid=IDx01192011x000001&kpid=00902169000&pla=&kispla=00902169000P&mktRedirect=y) here in the states for ~$35 ... I don't know what it would be in Jerusalem. I doubt it would be too much more expensive than that.

Comment: By the way, the fuel filter on this model is down on the firewall behind the engine  - pretty bad airflow back there and a real pita to change.  Had to take out the battery, remove a coolant line and the throttle body to get it done.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - Sounds like a chore ... but obviously you were up to the challenge ,-)

Comment: Well, I'm learning - slowly, slowly, but learning...